# web.py post variable from custom form

Tags: python, web.py

I'm new to Python web frameworks and chose web.py as a starting point.

I followed the tutorial on the web.py site and found how urls, POST, and GET work but I'm confused about how to use templates and template engines.

I have a custom html form and want to use it in my application. Should I use a "template engine" or should I use the web.py built-in form library?

Could any one give me an example of how custom form values can be posted to a web.py app? (Using forms without the built-in library.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web.py form library to render only parts of the form in your templates, see http://webpy.org/cookbook/form_fields

Answer (score 1):

Andrey Kuzmin's answer is not compatible for "custom forms". Tutorial that he linked is for generated forms via web.py
You can get the form variables of your custom form

```
    def POST(self):
        user_data = web.input()
        return user_data.YOUR_CUSTOM_HTML_FORM_VAR
```